# How to get "snowflake" value for user_id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to write a command that messages a specified user. The user can type something like `/warn @user insert warning here`. Here is the code:

```
    const user = await client.users
      .fetch(interaction.options.getString("user"))
      .catch(console.error);

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#FCE100")
      .setTitle(`⚠️ Warning!`)
      .setDescription(`${interaction.options.getString("warning")}`);
    await user.send({ embeds: embed }).catch(() => {
      interaction.channel.send("Error: user not found");
    });
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
user_id: Value "<@!9872345978#####>" is not snowflake.
```

How do I get the correct "snowflake" value to actually be able to DM the user?

Comment: You have to use `getUser` instead of `getString` and also change your `user` option type to `"USER"`

Comment: I assume it worked for you? Let me post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `getUser` instead of `getString` and also change your `user` option type to `"USER"` to make it work!